# Unable to invoke function defined in Objective-C++ from Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I tried the following program.

**wc.h**

```
int add(int, int);
int del (int, int);
```

**wc.mm**

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    NSLog (@"Inside Wrapper Add");
}

int del( int x, int y)
{
   NSLog (@"Inside Wrapper Multiply");

}
```

In AppDelegate.m

1) Included wc.h

2) call add(20,30);

I see the compilation error 'Unknown Type Name 'NSString'.

**what is My Understanding.**

1) I am trying to Mix C++ and Objective C.  That is, Invoking C++ from Objective C.

2) Found two ways to Achieve::

```
  1) Through Opaque Pointer ( PIMPL), Some how i achieve it through. 

  2) Using .mm ie: objective-C++ Source type which can be used to invoke pure C++.
```

**What is my Question?**

Having .mm [ Objective-C++] a function defined, why i am not able to invoke from Objective-C?

Kindly provide the input.

Comment: does that "`compilation error 'Unknown Type Name 'NSString"`" line come from adding "`add(20,30);`" to your AppDelegate.m file?  I don't see NSString anywhere else mentioned in your copied lines of code or in the rest of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You're unable to make the call from C to C++ (and the same principal applies when it's Objective) due to name mangling, something C++ does to your symbols to enable overloading.

If you declare `extern "C" int add(int, int);` for example, you declare that this C++ function needs to be callable by C and so no name mangling can occur (and no overloading can occur either).

Note that the C/ObjC side of things doesn't like the `extern "C"` notation, so your header files need to account for that (perhaps through an #ifdef __cplusplus).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if i declare with extern "C", can i again call another pure c++ function from add() ? Sorry if the question is very basic.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. The declaration doesn't change that the function is still C++, it only changes how it gets reached. It can call pure C++ and it in fact _is_ C++... it can create and use objects, etc.